# Lambda Expressions with multiple search criteria

Tags: vb.net, lambda

Currently I am searching through my list to find Customers that match on Address.
I need to match on both address and city. How do I rewrite my lambda Expression to match both criteria?

CustomerList.FindAll(Function(c) c.Address = addressToMatch)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keyword you are looking for is `AndAlso`.  It combines two separate checks into a single one which evaluates to `True` iff both components are also `True`

```
CustomerList.FindAll(Function(c) c.Address = addressToMatch AndAlso c.City = cityToMatch)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nuget package that allows you to search for strings across multiple properties

### https://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/

This will allow the following code...

```
CustomerList.Search(addressToMatch, 
                    Function(c) c.Address, 
                    Function(c) c.City)
```

When connected to a sql database, the sql produced will be similar to:

```
SELECT [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address], 
       [Extent1].[City] AS [City]
FROM   [dbo].[Table] AS [Extent1]
WHERE ([Extent1].[Address] LIKE N'%searchTerm%') 
   OR ([Extent1].[City] LIKE N'%searchTerm%')
```

Hope this helps